# Can We able to make Parent fields visible at child pagelayout?

Tags: page-layout, field-level-security

How to show four of the Parent fields at child layout?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind the fields being read-only, you can add [cross-object formula fields](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_cross_object.htm&language=en_US) to the child objects that reference the parent field values. This also allows you to pick appropriate names for the fields. These fields can then be added to detail or list view layouts.

(If you are willing to create Visualforce UI you can query the parent object at the same time as the child object and output the parent fields using expressions like `child.Parent__r.ParentField__c`.)

**PS**

For picklist parent fields, the formula filed in the child object should be of type Text and the TEXT function should be used in the formula:

```
TEXT(Parent_r.ParentField__c)
```

Comment: Thank You Keith. Now I am deciding to make formula fields because i don't have time to design a VF page for this.

Comment: @user5257 Absolutely. Only mentioned the Visualforce in case you were already using it.

Comment: Ok.Thanks. I am sorry parent field types are pick list type. Can i able to make it as formula fields?  If possible please provide me one example. Thanks in advance

Comment: @user5257 Added to answer.